# Logging in multiple files in multiple folders independently - log4j JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am working on a multithreading application in which i want to do logging at different locations using **log4j**.

**Scenario**:

> Folder1 ---> log1.log
>                       log2.log
>                       log3.log
>
> Folder2 ---> log1.log
>                       log2.log
>                       log3.log

I want my loggers to independently log into files.

Till now, i have created 3 **RollingFileAppenders**  which corresponds to 3 loggers for Folder1 but the problem is "I will have around 100's of folders and i don't want to write Appenders and loggers for them in my log4j.xml file".

```
<appender name="logfile1" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Folder1/log1.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="logfile2" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Folder1/log2.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="logfile3" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="Folder1/log3.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="Logger1" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile1" />
</logger>

<logger name="Logger2" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile2" />
</logger>

<logger name="Logger3" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="logfile3" />
</logger>
```

**The folders will be created at runtime**

**MY APPROACH:**
I want to instantiate my loggers according to my folder names and keep them in a hashmap like

```
HashMap<FolderName, HashMap<LoggerType, LoggerObject>>

FolderName: String 
LoggerType: it will be an Enum of log1, log2 and log3 
LoggerObject: It will a log4j Logger object
```

So, i will provide one method to get the LoggerObject like

```
public Logger getLoggerObject(String folderName, LoggerType loggerType){
     \\logic
     return loggerObject;
}

Logging.getLoggerObject("Folder1", LoggerType.log1).info("I am writing to log1.log file in Folder1");
```

Questions: 
1. I am not able to configure my LoggerObjects at runtime. Help me in doing that! 
2. How to configure my loggers for multiple folder locations and multiple logging files?

Comment: Are you open to migrating to log4j2?

Comment: yeah, if this scenario is possible. @D.B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you're open to switching to log4j2 I would suggest you do that and then use the [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) similar to the example in the [log4j2 FAQ regarding dynamically writing to separate log files](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files).

Here is some sample code to illustrate how you could change the folder and log file on the fly using the `ThreadContext`:

First we create 2 classes that implement `Runnable`:

```
package runners;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Runner1 implements Runnable{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void run() {
        //Set up the context before getting logger
        ThreadContext.put("logFolder", "Folder1");
        ThreadContext.put("logFileName", "log1");

        //Generate some logs
        log.info("here's the first thread");

        //Wait a while so that threads interleave
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Generate more logs
        log.debug("some debug in first thread");
        log.info("finishing first thread");

    }
}
```

and

```
package runners;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class Runner2 implements Runnable{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void run() {
        //Set up the context before getting logger
        ThreadContext.put("logFolder", "Folder2");
        ThreadContext.put("logFileName", "log2");

        //Generate some logs
        log.info("here's the second thread");
        log.debug("some debug in second thread");

    }
}
```

Now a basic controller class to create and start 2 threads:

```
package runners;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runner1());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runner2());
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

}
```

Lastly we need to configure log4j2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Routing name="MyRoutingAppender">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:logFolder}-$${ctx:logFileName}">
                <Route>
                    <File fileName="logs/${ctx:logFolder}/${ctx:logFileName}.log"
                        name="appender-${ctx:logFolder}-${ctx:logFileName}">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>[%date{ISO8601}][%-5level][%t] %m%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                    </File>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%date{ISO8601}][%-5level][%t] %m%n" />
        </Console>

    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="runners" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyRoutingAppender" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After you run the `Controller` you will see that two folders are generated with one file in each:

[image]

The logs from the first thread are in folder1 > log1 and logs from the second thread are in folder2 > log2

Note that I used a basic file appender but you can swap in a different appender within the routing appender to fit your needs.

Hope this helps to get you started.